# Python Iterator strangely skipping items

Tags: python, iterator

As part of a program that decodes a communication protocol (EDIFACT MSCONS) I have a class that gives me the next 'segment' of the message. The segments are delimited by an apostrophe "'". There may be newlines after the "'" or not.
Here's the code for that class:

```
class SegmentGenerator:
def __init__(self, filename):
    try:
        fh = open(filename)
    except IOError:
        print ("Error: file " + filename + " not found!")
        sys.exit(2)
    lines=[]
    for line in fh:
        line = line.rstrip()
        lines.append(line)
    if len(lines) == 1:
        msg = lines[0]
    else:
        msg = ''
        for line in lines:
            msg = msg + line.rstrip()
    self.segments=msg.split("'")
    self.iterator=iter(self.segments)

def next(self):
    try:
        return next(self.iterator)
    except StopIteration:
        return None

if __name__ == '__main__': #testing only
    sg = SegmentGenerator('MSCONS_21X000000001333E_20X-SUD-STROUM-M_20180807_000026404801.txt')
    for i in range(210436):
        if i > 8940:
            break
    print(sg.next())
```

To give an idea what the file looks like here's an excerpt of it:

```
UNB+UNOC:3+21X000000001333E:020+20X-SUD-STROUM-M:020+180807:1400+000026404801++TL'UNH+000026404802+MSCONS:D:04B:UN:1.0'BGM+7+000026404802+9'DTM+137:201808071400:203'RFF+AGI:6HYR67925RZUD_000000257860_00_E27'NAD+MS+21X000000001333E::020'NAD+MR+20X-SUD-STROUM-M::020'UNS+D'NAD+DP'LOC+172+LU0000010496200000000000050287886::89'DTM+163:201701010000?+01:303'DTM+164:201702010000?+01:303'LIN+1'PIA+5+1-1?:1.29.0:SRW'QTY+220:9.600'DTM+163:201701010000?+01:303'DTM+164:201701010015?+01:303'QTY+220:10.400'DTM+163:201701010015?+01:303'DTM+164:201701010030?+01:303'QTY+220:10.400'DTM+163:201701010030?+01:303'DTM+164:201701010045?+01:303'QTY+220:10.400'DTM+163:201701010045?+01:303'DTM+164:201701010100?+01:303'QTY+220:10.400'DTM+163:201701010100?+01:303'DTM+164:201701010115?+01:303'QTY+220:10.400'DTM+163:201701010115?+01:303'DTM+164:201701010130?+01:303'QTY+220:10.400'DTM+163:201701010130?+01:303'DTM+164:201701010145?+01:303'QTY+220:10.400'DTM+163:201701010145?+01:303'DTM+164:201701010200?+01:303'QTY+220:11.200'DTM+163:201701010200?+01:303' ...
```

The file I have a problem with has 210000 of those segments. I tested the code and everything works fine. The list of segments is complete and I get one segment after the other correctly until the end of the list.

I use the segments as input to a statemachine that gets new segments from an instance of SegmentGenerator.

Here's an excerpt:

```
    def DTMstarttransition(self,segment):
    match=re.search('DTM\+(.*?):(.*?):(.*?)($|\+.*|:.*)',segment)
    if match:
        if match.group(1) == '164':
            self.currentendtime=self.dateConvert(match.group(2),match.group(3))
            return('DTMend',self.sg.next())
    return('Error',segment + "\nExpected DTM segment didn't match")
```

The method returns the name of the next state and the next segment sg.next(), sg being an instance of SegmentGenerator.

However at the 8942st segment the call to sg.next() doesn't give me the next segment but the second last of the list of segments!

I traced the function calls (with the autologging module):

```
TRACE:segmentgenerator.SegmentGenerator:next:CALL *() **{}
TRACE:segmentgenerator.SegmentGenerator:next:RETURN 'DTM+164:201702010000?+01:303'
TRACE:__main__.MSCONSparser:QTYtransition:RETURN ('DTMstart', 'DTM+164:201702010000?+01:303')
TRACE:__main__.MSCONSparser:DTMstarttransition:CALL *('DTM+164:201702010000?+01:303',) **{}
TRACE:__main__.MSCONSparser:dateConvert:CALL *('201702010000?+01', '303') **{}
TRACE:__main__.MSCONSparser:dateConvert:RETURN datetime.datetime(2017, 2, 1, 0, 0)
TRACE:segmentgenerator.SegmentGenerator:next:CALL *() **{}
TRACE:segmentgenerator.SegmentGenerator:next:RETURN 'UNT+17872+000026404802'
TRACE:__main__.MSCONSparser:DTMstarttransition:RETURN ('DTMend', 'UNT+17872+000026404802')
TRACE:__main__.MSCONSparser:DTMendtransition:CALL *('UNT+17872+000026404802',) **{}
```

UNT+... isn't the next segment it should be a LIN segment.
But how is this possible? Why does SegmentGenerator work when I test it with the main function in its module and doesn't work correctly after thousands of calls from the other module?

All the segments are there from beginning to end. I can verify this from the interpreter, since the list sg.segments stays available after program stop. len(sg.segments) is 210435 but my program stops after 8942. So it is clearly a problem with the iterator.

The files (3 python files and data example) can be found on [Github](https://github.com/jay-christnach/mscons-parser) in branch 'next' if you like to test the whole thing.

Comment: is it possible rstrip is doing it?
Also, it is possible that the variables you're using are outside the scope. You placed a few in loops and defined them (i.e. msg) and then use them later. This could cause issues.

Comment: rstrip is used to get rid of CR/LF when the input file has them (more human readable form). msg is used temporarily to extract the list of segments. All the segments are there from beginning to end. I can verify this from the interpreter, since the list sg.segments stays available after program stop. len(sg.segments) is 210435 but my program stops after 8942. So it is clearly a problem with the iterator.

Comment: You're sure you're not calling `sg.next()` anywhere else in your program? Or even `next(sg.iterator)`?

Comment: have you tried changing the scope of your variables, as I mentioned?

Comment: @NationWidePants :Thanks for wanting to help. The problem was with my debugging. See my own answer. Problem solved, thanks again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turned out that a segment 'DTM+164:201702010000?+01:303' existed a second time further down in the file and that indeed that one is followed by a UTM segment. So the problem is with the protocol states themselves and the iterator was working correctly.
So sorry that I bothered you with my wrong assumption. Thanks for wanting to help!

Answer (score 0):

I think it's possible there is a double apostrophe '' in your data file, near the 8942th apostrophe.

In this case your code will continue to read the whole file reading all 210435 segments.

But if you have the condition that tests the result of `sg.next()`, then that would be falsey on the 8942th iteration, and I'm guessing this is causing your program to abort.

eg:

```
while sg.next():
   # some processing here
```

If I'm completely wrong then I'd be interested in seeing the behaviour of this: - where len and iterations should equal.

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    fn = sys.argv[1]
    sg = SegmentGenerator(fn)

    print("Num segments:", len(sg.segments))
    i = 0
    value = 'x'
    while value:
        value = sg.next()
        i += 1
        print(i, value)

    print("Num iterations:", i)
```

Comment: Thanks Richard. I ran your suggested code snippet and Num iterations and Num segements are equal 210435. There is also no double apostrophe at the place where the other part of the program goes wrong. I'm also very sure that sg.next() isn't called elsewhere (used trace for that). I verified with a conditional breakpoint and manually called sg.next() and got the wrong segment (always the second last). This is really weird now. I think for anybody to further help me he will need the whole program.